# How to send specific byte array in javascript via HTTP POST

Tags: javascript, jquery, http, byte

I'm stuck at the following situation.
I want to send bytes via http post, using javascript and jQuery to a server. I figured out that I can send bytes via `String.fromCharCode(...)` with a mime-type of `application/octet-stream` or `text/plain; charset=x-user-defined`

But now here's the problem. I have to send a specific amount of bytes with values greater than 127. (the packet, if sniffed in wireshark, has to consist of e.g. 5 bytes)

Is this possible with jQuery? Or is this possible with javascript at all?
(e.g. I need to send 1 byte --> 0xAF)

Is it possible to send this one byte, 0xAF ? Or will it be always 2 bytes because the value is bigger than 127?

Comment: I'm curious why you need to do this.

Comment: I wonder why you face the problem. Everything that is under `0xFF` is one byte. What is the issue?

Comment: You can use [`void send(ArrayBuffer data)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FXMLHttpRequest#send())

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To clearify this for whoever may concern.

The request is embedded in a HTTP-POST frame. This  frame is, depending on its mime type, encoded. 
For any textual encoding, including application/octet-stream, bytes are converted to its textual representation.
For byte values > 127, this means, there need to be 2 bytes to textual represent this.

In my case, i needed to ensure that a value of e.g. 128 MUST be 1 byte transmitted.(Through server piped requests to another protocol - modbus)

Solution was to use an arraybuffer, altough this meant IE>=10.